# MySQL: join with OR clause slows down

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a simple MySQL InnoDB database with two tables: `users` and `dialogues`. I am trying to make a LEFT JOIN query, however, I've ran into a performance problem.

When I execute the following statement,

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT u.id FROM users u
LEFT JOIN dialogues d ON u.id = d.creator_id
```

I get a response that DB uses SELECT types `index` and `ref`, which is totally fine.

However, when I add an additional clause:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT u.id FROM users u
LEFT JOIN dialogues d ON (u.id = d.creator_id OR u.id = d.target_id)
```

suddenly the DB indicates that it uses `all` SELECT type when JOINing, which in turn makes the actual query multiple times slower.

Is there something that could be done to make DB use more effective SELECT type in the second example?
`d.creator_id` and `d.target_id` columns have foreign keys connected to `u.id`.

Comment: Your query example is a bit non-sensical because you are using a `left join` and only select values from the first table.

Comment: Does it change if you use `u.id IN ( d.creator_id, d.target_id)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, totally missed that! This is just an example, the results from JOIN are definitely to be used :)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thanks for the suggestion! It indeed changes SELECT type to `index`, however, it is still significantly slower.

Comment: Luckily, there's an Edit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually faster to do two `left join`s and `coalesce()` in the `select`:

```
SELECT d.*,
       COALESCE(uc.name, ut.name) as name
FROM dialogues d LEFT JOIN
     users uc 
     ON uc.id = d.creator_id LEFT JOIN
     users ut
     ON ut.id = d.target_id
```